# Set the Document Template of a Document Library programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am creating a Document Library from an event receiver.  I would like to change the Document Library to a custom Word document.  In the user interface, this is simply done by changing the Template URL value in the Document Template property under Document Library Advanced Settings.  I'm not sure how to do this via code.

I would also be open to creating a list template with my document template already setup, but I'd prefer to go the other route so I retain the flexibility of setting up each document library with a different template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Specify it within your content type definition in the elements.xml for the feature and add a module file reeference.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ContentType ID="0x010100DC863B72929F8148A8A84BF932C5356701"
           Name="Word 2007"
           Group="CEO Content Types"
           Sealed="FALSE"
           FeatureId="332a1967-3ae1-498b-ba11-f03743cab20b">
    <FieldRefs />
    <DocumentTemplate TargetName="Untitled.docx"/>
  </ContentType>
  <Module Name="WordDefaultFile" Url="_cts/MyWord" RootWebOnly="TRUE">
    <File Url="Untitled.docx" Name="Untitled.docx" Type="Ghostable"></File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Copy the template to your feature directory and add an ElementFile reference to it within the ElementsManifest section of your feature.xml.

```
<ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="MyWord-CT.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="Untitled.docx"/>
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```